# How can Apache Spark history-server refer to Amazon S3?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

[version]
Apache Spark 2.2.0
Hadoop 2.7

I want to set up Apache Spark histroy server.
Spark events log located in Amazon S3.
I can save log file in S3, but cannot read from history server.

Apache Spark installed at `/usr/local/spark`
so, `$SPARK_HOME` is `/usr/local/spark`

```
$ cd /usr/local/spark/sbin
$ sh start-history-server.sh
```

I got following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:230)
....
```

my `spark-defaults.conf` is below

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.history.provider org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.history.fs.logDirectory s3a://xxxxxxxxxxxxx
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir s3a://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I installed this 2 jar files in `/usr/local/spark/jars/`

```
aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
```

but error is same.

What is wrong?

Comment: Is the `CLASSPATH` correct?

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer

`$ echo $CLASSPATH  /usr/local/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar:/usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following in spark-defaults.conf file and retry again.

spark.driver.extraClassPath     :/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/* :
spark.executor.extraClassPath   :/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:

Comment: @Blue-Pixel did you find the solution?